# Stopping a variable from running as a funtction in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have a service accessing a MYSQL database, but the value returned by the server is stored as `result.COUNT(*)` (I'm counting the entries in a table), when I try to use this result, it seems to try and execute a function with the parameter `*`.

```
     console.log(result[0].COUNT(*));
                                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*'
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is SQL function, not result[0] property, javascript won't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use bracket notation it should work, e.g.:

```
console.log(result[0]['COUNT(*)']);
```

You can also provide an alias in your SQL query, e.g.

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as UserCount FROM Users"
```

then

```
console.log(result[0].UserCount);
```